# How to plot a line with two colors in parallel using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I want to have a single line that has two colors in parallel, e.g. for green and red:[image]

I have achieved this as follows:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
y = np.exp(x)

plt.plot(x,y,color='r')
plt.plot(x,y+0.01,color='g')
plt.show()
```

The problem is that when I zoom in the lines start to separate. In addition, this approach does not work if the line is nearly vertical (then `x` must be increased). Is there anyway to plot a *single* line that has two **parallel** colors?

Comment: That looks like a line with two parallel colors to me :-)

Comment: See https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/patheffects_guide.html

Comment: @QuangHoang not really, it are two separate lines. And when I zoom in, they separate from one another... plus, when the line is vertical this approach does not work...